# Vuejs app not loading with webpack4 and splitchunks 'all'

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I have a vuejs webapp that I am migrating from webpack3 to webpack4. I'm trying to update the config to use the new optimization tools, but when I run it, my app doesn't load. The main.js file exists but it doesn't seem to do anything, and dev tools console doesn't show anything.

If I don't use `chunks: 'all'` then my app works, but then my js files are huge. Can anyone help me fix my config file? Thanks in advance!

Note also that I'm using aspnetcore.

I show below:

1. webpackconfig.js
2. package.json
3. entry js file
4. html index file
5. webpack output

Here's my webpack config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDev = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
        entry: {
            'main': './ClientApp/boot-app.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common',
                'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/components'),
                'tools': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/tools'),
                'base': path.resolve(__dirname, './ClientApp/'),
                'img': path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/img')
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.vue$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'vue-loader' },
                { test: /\.js$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'babel-loader' },
                {
                    test: /\.(css|scss|sass)/,
                    use: [
                        isDev ? 'vue-style-loader' : MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        optimization: {
            runtimeChunk: false,
            splitChunks: {
                chunks: 'all',
                maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
                minSize: 0,
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendor: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: function (module) {
                            // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
                            // or node_modules/packageName
                            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

                            // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
                            return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(), // so that file hashes don't change unexpectedly
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].css',
                chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].css'
            }),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        ]
    }];
};
```

Here's my package.json

```js
{
    "name": "my app",
    "description": "my app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "lverre",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
        "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
        "css-element-queries": "^0.4.0",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
        "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
        "hashed-module-id-plugin": "^1.0.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "url-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.11",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.0",
        "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1",
        "vuex-router-sync": "^5.0.0",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

Here's my boot-app.js file which is the webpack entry:

```js
import 'core-js/es6/promise'
import 'core-js/es6/array'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import router from './router'
import store from 'tools/store'
import App from 'components/app-root'

sync(store, router);
const app = new Vue({
    store,
    router,
    ...App
});
app.$mount('#app');
```

Here's my Index.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="~/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"><span style="line-height:100vh;width:100vw;text-align:center;display:inline-block;background:#EEE;"><img src="~/img/wheel.gif" style="margin:0px 4px 4px 4px;" />Loading Web App...</span></div>
    <script src="~/dist/main.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, here's the webpack output:

```
1>v12.14.1
1>Performing first-run Webpack build...
1>Hash: 8f64c9e617681a7d9069
1>Version: webpack 4.41.5
1>Child
1>    Hash: 8f64c9e617681a7d9069
1>    Time: 17962ms
1>    Built at: 02/20/2020 5:14:45 PM
1>                                  Asset      Size                   Chunks                         Chunk Names
1>                          0.b492eb23.js  13.5 KiB                        0  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          1.b4f894be.js  9.14 KiB                        1  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          2.9dab94c2.js  36.7 KiB                        2  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          3.f31dcc88.js  33.7 KiB                        3  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          4.dde409ef.js  10.3 KiB                        4  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          5.39b4a0b9.js  6.82 KiB                        5  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                          6.559365e1.js  5.71 KiB                        6  [emitted] [immutable]
1>                                main.js   880 KiB                     main  [emitted]              main
1>          npm.babel-runtime.e944a466.js  13.9 KiB        npm.babel-runtime  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.babel-runtime
1>                npm.core-js.ceba3f6f.js   215 KiB              npm.core-js  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.core-js
1>             npm.css-loader.48e5a965.js  3.02 KiB           npm.css-loader  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.css-loader
1>          npm.inline-worker.8dfd1980.js  2.76 KiB        npm.inline-worker  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.inline-worker
1>                npm.process.e2f745dc.js  5.85 KiB              npm.process  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.process
1>    npm.regenerator-runtime.4488ff8a.js  26.4 KiB  npm.regenerator-runtime  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.regenerator-runtime
1>           npm.setimmediate.bb06f868.js  7.21 KiB         npm.setimmediate  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.setimmediate
1>      npm.timers-browserify.57593fb7.js  2.67 KiB    npm.timers-browserify  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.timers-browserify
1>     npm.vue-hot-reload-api.2af5ecec.js  7.84 KiB   npm.vue-hot-reload-api  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vue-hot-reload-api
1>             npm.vue-loader.bd373c54.js  3.41 KiB           npm.vue-loader  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vue-loader
1>             npm.vue-router.b7224a0b.js  76.2 KiB           npm.vue-router  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vue-router
1>       npm.vue-style-loader.0121d20d.js  8.38 KiB     npm.vue-style-loader  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vue-style-loader
1>                    npm.vue.3fb7d7f1.js   327 KiB                  npm.vue  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vue
1>       npm.vuex-router-sync.7e7d78fc.js  2.18 KiB     npm.vuex-router-sync  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vuex-router-sync
1>                   npm.vuex.97f31906.js  30.7 KiB                 npm.vuex  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.vuex
1>                npm.webpack.d644d8a7.js  1.68 KiB              npm.webpack  [emitted] [immutable]  npm.webpack
1>                        opt.fb154780.js   760 KiB                      opt  [emitted] [immutable]  opt
1>                  opt~staff.f7ca55c0.js  77.1 KiB                opt~staff  [emitted] [immutable]  opt~staff
1>                      staff.3a9db472.js  3.21 MiB                    staff  [emitted] [immutable]  staff
1>    Entrypoint main = npm.core-js.ceba3f6f.js npm.babel-runtime.e944a466.js npm.vue-style-loader.0121d20d.js npm.vue.3fb7d7f1.js npm.webpack.d644d8a7.js npm.css-loader.48e5a965.js npm.process.e2f745dc.js npm.setimmediate.bb06f868.js npm.timers-browserify.57593fb7.js npm.vue-hot-reload-api.2af5ecec.js npm.vue-loader.bd373c54.js npm.vue-router.b7224a0b.js npm.vuex-router-sync.7e7d78fc.js npm.vuex.97f31906.js main.js
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, but not using Vue. Lets see if you get the same progress as me. Try this: Comment out all the import lines in your main.js file, and put a breakpoint in Chrome on the first line of executable code. Does it hit the breakpoint? I find it hits the breakpoint, but as soon as I uncomment even a single import line, the breakpoint is not hit, and no code it run other than the webpack bootloader stuff.